# Simplify: $\frac{\sin^6 x}{1-\tan^2 x}+\frac{\cos^6 x}{1-\cot^2 x}$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\frac{\sin^6 x}{1-\tan^2 x}+\frac{\cos^6 x}{1-\cot^2 x} = \;\text{?}$$

My work:

$$\frac{(\sin^2x)^3}{1-\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}+\frac{(\cos^2x)^3}{1-\dfrac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}}=
\frac{(\sin^2x)^3}{(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)/\cos^2x}+
\frac{(\cos^2x)^3}{(\sin^2x-\cos^2x)/\sin^2x} = \dots$$

I've transformed $\tan$ and $\cot$, and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: This is almost impossible to understand. Please reformat using MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\sin^2x=a,\cos^2x=b\implies a+b=?$

$$\dfrac{ab(a-b)(a+b)}{a-b}=?$$

What if $a-b=0?$